# What is default Windows Azure Hosted Services behavior?

Tags: azure, cloud, load-balancing, failover, round-robin

When deploying a web-role to the Windows Azure cloud, what is the default behavior in terms of load balancing? Are there any?

The reason for my question is, that we have the Traffic Manager where you can specify load balancing, fail over and round robin. However, if I do not enable this, how does Azure work behind the curtain then?

The default recommendation in regards to SLA is always at least two instances; but are these two instances serving requests or only one? Hence, default behavior is fail over?

Thanks in advance for any clarifications regarding this matter as I have been unsuccessful finding it on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default *should* be round robin, but it is not always 100% guaranteed.

One thing that is sure, is that it is not failover load balancing. The idea is that all your instances are equally loaded, but it cannot be 100% guaranteed all the time.

**UPDATE**

Nothing in this world is 100% guaranteed :) Even the SLA for compute instances is 99.95% and not 100%. Traffic manager has nothing to do with multi-instance deployments. Traffic manager only takes place when you have deployments across geographic regions.

I've been using, exploring, tweaking, developing for-, porting to- Windows Azure since it's first public CTP back in 2008. I can't remember where do I get all the information from, but the compute load balancer shall be using round robin or similar algorythm (and defenitelly not failover) to spread the load across your instances. Even more, it is "stickyless" if I may say so. Which means that there is no guarantee a request from one user will hit the same instance in the next call.

Some resources on Windows Azure (older and newer):

http://www.davidchappell.com/writing/white_papers/introducing_windows_azure_v1-chappell.pdf

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/11/12/windows-azure-load-balancer-timeout-details.aspx

Also, something worth mentioning is that, with the latest release there is also SLA for single instance roles: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/

> Additionally, we will monitor all of your individual role instances
>   and guarantee that 99.9% of the time we will detect when a role
>   instance’s process is not running and initiate corrective action.

Comment: When you say not 100% guaranteed, what do you mean with this statement? Is this because Microsoft wants us to use Traffic Manager or is some technicalities in the platform? Any material is appreciated. Can I ask where you have the information? Thanks.

Comment: Hi astaykov,
I am sorry if you got the feeling I was questioning your knowledge - I am just curious to why this information is so hard to come by. I started using Azure a little over a year ago, and I am very pleased. Of course nothing is 100% guaranteed - I was just wondering about your "should" comment - that's all. I appreciate the time and depth you have provided; thank you very much. Voted.

Comment: "should", because I am not 100% sure. As for hard to find - you are right, that the answer of your particular question is indeed hard to find in the publicly availailable information. And my answer is based on my experience, knowladge and interaction with the system and the community (other experts)

Comment: Just FYI here - but while the load balancer is round robin, it also respects HTTP keep alives (1.1).  So, there is a good chance that the same browser will hit the same instance behind the load balancer.  You should not expect to see the exact same browser bounce instance to instance in between requests reliably.  That might be obvious to some, but folks often wonder why they keep hitting instance 0 during testing on single browser.

Comment: @dunnry thanks for that clarification! I still thing this should be part of the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

@astaykov pretty much covered it. I want to expand on this because of the comment about Traffic Manager and 100% SLA.

I've never heard of a hosting provider offering 100% SLA. That would mean *nothing* ever goes wrong: Software crash, OS update, OS crash, hardware crash, network interruption, power interruption, DNS interruption... *Something* at *some point* will render a server (or VM) unavailable for a period of time.

Windows Azure has a Serivce Level Agreement (SLA) for Cloud Services, Storage, SQL Database, SQL Reporting, Service Bus, Access Control, Caching, and CDN (see all SLA details [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/)). For this question, the Cloud Services SLA is relevant, providing 99.95% availability.

Occasionally, a given role instance will be unavailable. You can pretty much assure yourself of this. There are upgrades to OS images (both for the Guest OS and the Host OS), hardware failures, etc. This issue is not specific to Windows Azure; any cloud or hosting offering will have these types of outages.

To improve uptime availability, multiple instances should be deployed. The instances are then split up across *fault domains*, meaning they're located on different hardware, different racks, isolated so that if something like a network segment or power connection fails (imagine a server rack's network panel shorting out), only a subset of instances are affected. The load balancer will continue to distribute traffic to the healthy instances (albeit at a reduced capacity until replacement instances come online).

On to Traffic Manager: This is a way to distribute traffic across geographical areas, either for failover or performance. In the former case, you'll have services running in a separate data center, which gives a good "high availability" story for your app (imagine the primary data center going offline for some reason). In the latter case, you can offer better performance to customers when you have a worldwide presence.

Comment: Hi David,

Thank you for your answer. I don't know where you come up with the 100% SLA, but let me clarify why I asked into @astaykov comment about round-robing not being 100% guaranteed. This had nothing to do with the SLA, but the mechanism for the instances; i mean - if it is not round-robin a 100% of the, what is it then? Round-robin 90% of the time, 5% one instance, 3% load-balancing, 2% fail-over? I know this can seem provocative - it's not - I just want to learn about the mechanism when leaving out the Traffic Manager parameter. Btw; thank you for a clear explanation of TM :-)

Comment: @MichaelMortensen, if you take a look at "dunnry"s comment to my answer, you find the answer your self - it is stickyless round robin, with HTTP Keep Alive respect. So what it makes - it is a round robin, but some (keep alive) requests may end up in hitting one and the same instance. I think it fully covers your question and concerns.

Comment: @astaykov I agree - and I have marked your answer as an answer. Like you, I am just troubled this is not part of the official documentation. Cheers, mate - and thanks again. Hopefully other can benefit from the Q/A as well.